# How to compare elements in sublist python?

Tags: python, list, sublist

How to compare elements in sublist in python? I want to compare index 1 and index 2 with other list. and want not matched sublist

```
list1 =  [['10.100.10.37', 19331, '2020-9-28 6:38:10', 15, 16], ['10.100.10.37', 29331, '2020-9-28 6:38:10', 15 ,17]]
list2 = [ ['10.100.10.37', 19331, '2020-9-28 6:38:10', 15],['10.100.10.37', 19331, '2020-9-28 9:38:10', 15],['10.100.10.37', 21301, '2020-9-28 6:38:10', 15]]


new_items = []
for item in list2:
    if not any(x[1] == item[1] for x in list1):
       if not any(x[2] != item[2] for x in list1):       
           new_items.append(item)
   
print(new_items)
```

I got Output as (Actual Output) :

```
[['10.100.10.37', 21301, '2020-9-28 6:38:10', 15]]
```

Expected Output:

```
[['10.100.10.37', 19331, '2020-9-28 9:38:10', 15], 
['10.100.10.37', 21301, '2020-9-28 6:38:10', 15]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main issue in your code: the nested `any` function call will not do what you want (the code doesn't compare the first and second indexes of each list in `list1` with respective indexes of sublists in `list2`)

List comprehension and an `any` call will do the trick:

```py
new_items = [item for item in list2 if not any(item[1] == x[1] and item[2] == x[2] for x in list1)]
```

Version using slices (in case you need to increase the number of consecutive checks):

```py
new_items = [item for item in list2 if not any(item[1:3] == x[1:3] for x in list1)]
```

Alternative version using `filter` (somewhat more straightforward from question):

```py
tmp = [x[1:3] for x in list1]
new_items = list(filter(lambda x: not x[1:3] in tmp, list2))
```